# Auto reload map in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, swift

I am building an iOS app in `swift` that use the `google maps`.

The app show the POI near the user, and when I move the map I refresh the POI using a refresh button

```
@IBAction func refreshPlaces(sender: AnyObject) {
fetchNearbyPlaces(mapView.camera.target)
}
```

Can I can refresh the POI when I move the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you declare that your view controller conforms to the  `GMSMapViewDelegate` and that you set `self.mapView.delegate = self` in that view controller (usually in `viewDidLoad`).

Then add the rolling method in your view controller:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
    fetchNearbyPlaces(position.target)
}
```